# predict conditional mean of one potential outcome in causal forest?

Tags: random-forest, causality, causalml

I fit a [`causal_forest()`](https://grf-labs.github.io/grf/reference/causal_forest.html) and used [`predict()`](https://grf-labs.github.io/grf/reference/predict.causal_forest.html) to get estimates of tau(X) = E[Y(1) - Y(0) | X].

How can I get estimates of E[Y(0) | X] alone ?

Thank you !

Comment: The online documentation has an example here: https://grf-labs.github.io/grf/articles/muhats.html